# can't update state with props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-component, react-state

found this : https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#new-lifecycle-getderivedstatefromprops

I'm pretty sure this is what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to update my state when prop changes in an effort to have the view update when my prop changes.

(why does what I'm describing sound like rocket science? Basically in neanderthal speak Array go to View)

My array is from a subscription (no not html.get, it's just a poor man's store).

I subscribed in the parent and pass it as a prop because apparently having it in the same component wouldn't update.

my issue is that `getDerivedStateFromProps()` triggers on init but not on update (for some reason the init value isn't the one passed from the parent) and no longer triggers after that when I do the click that ultimately correctly console.logs in the parent.

`componentDidUpdate()` on the other hand doesn't trigger at all.

I have this :

```
interface Props {
    mything: string
}

interface State {
    mything: string
}

class Component extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props: any) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { mything: ''} 
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: Props, state: State) {
    console.log('hi', props);
    return {tanks: props.mything}
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props, prevState: State){
    console.log('ho');
    if(prevProps.mything !== this.props.mything){
        this.setState(state => ({
            mything: this.props.mything
        }));
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props, nextContext: Props): void {
    console.log('d')
    this.setState(state => ({
        mything: this.props.mything
    }));
  }

  render() {
      return(
         {this.state.mything.map((thing: thingType, index: number) => {
            return (
               <div key={index} />
               </div>
                   )
         })}
      )
  }
```

props is correctly passed and readable. I can iterate over it successfully but for updates that's apparently not what I want to do, I want to copy it to state and iterate over that.

hence why in the above code I am pointing to state's mything not prop's mything.

I'm not interested in using `componentDidUpdate()` or `getDerivedStateFromProps()` I just thought they would be my solution, and as you can see above I tried `componentWillReceiveProps()` with even less success plus I learned it's getting deprecated. there's `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()` but the name alone is enough for me to understand I'd be swimming upstream.

but as it stands I cannot find a way to copy props to state. (and of course have it happen on props change).

Comment: Please read [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) as well. It seems that [this part](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state) is your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that declaring state in the parent and passing state (instead of a global var) to the child was sufficient for the child using props to update always, no method in the child needed.

this stuff is not obvious and should be b̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶ explained in the docs.